# multiple background slider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create slider backgrounds. Basically create a container and put couple images inside of this container, each image is a responsive background for the whole page. In result we can have multiple backgrounds and a slider to change them. Well if I put all measurement in px than everything is work.but as soon I put in percentage since it suppose to be a responsive design. It get me instead of horizontal scroll a vertical one.

Something like that:

```
<div class="slider-wrap">

        <div class="slide" id="slide-0">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;  
    text-decoration: none; /*clear href decoration*/

}

body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100vh;

}

.slider-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    float:left;
}


#slide-1 {
    background-image: url(img/m_m.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide-0 {
    background-image: url(img/b_m.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

So how to make a multiple background images with horizontal scroll

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you putting the measurements in px then changing to percentages?

Comment: in the class slide if you change it to let say 200px it will put 2 images floating left.

Comment: What if you just put the background image on the slider-wrap then just change the image url using javascript? That way you won't need the slide divs

Comment: Well it actually might work too. But for educational purpose I would like to know how to do it in css

Comment: Look at how I implemented the menu here and see if it's what you want: http://rotaract.twazua.com/

Comment: well It looks nice... I do similar things, multiple background images and if you browse from smart phone you can slide the background by swiping the screen.

Comment: Thank you. That is triggered by the 'hover' state. When you hover over a menu, the bg image changes. What will be the trigger in your case?

Comment: swipe the screen in mobile version and link in desktop version. I just thought it might be much easier in css :)

Comment: something like here https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Fkczq  However the problem is that container is fixed size